# Does TwilioResponse.Sms("message") command add the string as new element to the current response?

Tags: twilio

Does twilio's Response.Sms command add the messages as new messages to the existing response or will it overwrite if I call this command again? 
Basically what I am trying to find out is if I have a list of collections containing sms messages for a singe request from Twilio can I simply loop through this collection and call the Response.Sms each time to load the messages? Or will it overwrite?

Something like this:

```
  foreach (DtocollectionList text in ...)
  {
         Response.Sms(text.message);
  }
```

Will this add each of my text.message to the XML list or do I need to create my own XML Serialization to load the response?

Please let me know as I am not clear on this Twilio Sms command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

I assume your using the TwilioResponse object to generate your TwiML.  I that is the case, the code above will add multiple `<Sms>` verbs to the response, meaning Twilio will send multiple SMS messages.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes. I am using TwilioResponse object to generate the TwiML. So I plan to pass the list of actual sms messages to this Response in a loop (available in my DTO) expecting that multiple SMS messages will be sent for one request.